# Cannot connect MSAccess to MySQL with ODBC

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I have installed MySQL (8.0.35) and it is working on the sever and I can interrogate it and create tables using the command line tool. The server is running on a separate machine to the client machine using MSAccess as a front end
I am using a windows 10 PC (all latest updates) with MSAccess 2019 to connect to the server via ODBC. I start with a blank database.

I go into control panel and administrative tools and set up  the ODBC driver - the latest connector (Connector/ODBC 8.2.0). Install the connection and test it and it is working fine.

I then go in to Access and try to access the database (NewDataSource>From Other data Sources >ODBC data sources) choose link to data source then choose the connection I set up in the step above (and tested) and get the error message [Microsoft]{ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and the application #0

I suspect this is a 64b s 32b DSN problem, and I have found the 32b Connector(Connector/ODBC 8.0.35 ), but I cannot install it because it requires  MS Visual Studio 2019 x86 Redistribution installed and this will not install, the log file says there is a newer version already installed on the computer already when I try to install the require redistributable..

I have also tried to create a connector from within MSAccess when selecting 'new' data source and clicking new, however, access does not list the MySQL connector as an option.

I would welcome any thoughts on how to resolve the impasse.

Comment: You need to install odbc driver for `MySQL` database.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.
I was trying to install the Visual Studio Community 2019 edition when I installed the Visual Studio professional edition the installation went ahead with no issues and the MSQL 8.0.35 installed without issue.

I was then able to have a connector Access could use.

I am not clear what the differences in the community vs the professional edition are however this seemed to make the difference in this case.